# Generic data structure libraries for C?

Tags: linked-list, binary-tree

Which libraries do you guys use for generic data structures like linked list, binary tree etc.?

What are the most common, efficient libraries? Can you name some?

Comment: I think we just copy them from *K&R*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GDSL - The Generic Data Structures Library](http://home.gna.org/gdsl/)

[Gnulib - The GNU Portability Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/)

[GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/)

[SGLIB](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Somehow I'm not surprised that that first one is the first result on Google when you search for "generic data structure libraries for c"

Comment: my point is that it's a question easily answered by a quick Google search. And that it's funny that there's a library with nearly the exact name of the title of the question...

Comment: @pib: so presumably your comment would be more appropriate under the poster's question.

Comment: @pib: I dont think you understood the question. It was about experiences with libraries. I asked what people are using which cant be found by a simple google search. maybe you can tell about what you use ha?

Answer (score 1):

In C....if you're on linux

http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.22/

not sure about windows.....I don't use it :P

Answer (score 0):

[glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) contains a lot of data structures.