# C data structure libraries

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generic data structure libraries for C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159555/generic-data-structure-libraries-for-c)

Starting off in C programming and wondering if anyone is aware of any library containing implementations of data structures such as linked list, hash maps etc ?

Comment: If you starting off, might be worth implementing those on your own...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445/are-there-c-library-resources-similar-to-cs-boost-library

Comment: If you're looking to use a pre-built data structure library, have you considered using C++ instead?

Answer (score 0):

glib.  Hard to use if you're just-starting-off because you actually have to know how to get around in pointers.

It's reasonably standard for applications that want to use that sort of thing (excuse the wishy-washy opining).

An option I usually prefer is to wrap C++ STL with C APIs myself.  I don't know if there's a standard converter for this.  But this is because most developers I work with understand C++-to-C APIs (part of the corporate code landscape at my firm) and STL much better than glib, in which client code tends to be egregiously error prone.

Comment: Answer was from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445/are-there-c-library-resources-similar-to-cs-boost-library